# Spring MongoDb configuration fails when using .credential builder

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to configure Spring to work with MongoDB and I run into an error if I use the `.credential` option from the builder, but no error if I add my credentials to the connection string directly. Here's my code:

```
@Override
protected MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings() {
    //ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString("mongodb+srv://cluster0.some.mongodb.net/someDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
    ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString("mongodb+srv://someUser:somePassword@cluster0.some.mongodb.net/someDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority");

    return MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
            //.credential(MongoCredential.createCredential("someUser", "someDB", "somePassword".toCharArray()))
            .build();
}
```

The uncommented code works perfectly, but if I try using the credentials in the commented section and using the simpler commented ConnectionString instead, I get auth failures. The solution must be very simple, but I can't figure it out or find good examples.

Comment: add ```&authSource=someDB``` at last in connection string and check.

Comment: With MongoDB v4.2.8 and Java Driver 4.2.0, both ways of connecting to the server work fine from a Java application.

Comment: @Harshit that didn't work, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I am using Spring boot 2.3.11  and Mongo/Maas 4.2.11

Following code for mongodb connectivity from java works for me.

Upvote if its works for you or anyone :)

```
public @Bean MongoClientFactoryBean mongo() {
    MongoClientFactoryBean mongo = new MongoClientFactoryBean();

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustStoreFile));
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "trustStoreFilePassword");

    // The admin database hosts all the user credentials, so hardcoding it
    MongoCredential mongoCredential = MongoCredential.createScramSha256Credential(username, "admin", mongoPas.toCharArray());

    MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .retryWrites(true)
            .applyToConnectionPoolSettings(builder ->
                    builder.maxConnectionIdleTime(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
            .applyToSslSettings(ssl -> {
                ssl.enabled(true);
                ssl.invalidHostNameAllowed(true);
            })
            .applyToClusterSettings(builder -> {
                builder.hosts(Arrays.asList(
                        new ServerAddress(hostname, port)
                ));
            })
            .build();

    mongo.setMongoClientSettings(settings);
    mongo.setCredential(new MongoCredential[]{mongoCredential});
    return mongo;
}
```

Inject fongo in MongoTemplate along with databaseName

```
@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new MongoTemplate( mongo().getObject(),databaseName);
}
```